# How to implement quick navigation in a huge circle genlist on in a Tizen native API app?

Tags: tizen

The [circle genlist](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/wearable/component-circle-genlist/) is great for selecting from a list of items like for example contacts. If the list is huge though navigation gets a little cumbersome. There is a feature called [fast rotary action](https://developer.tizen.org/design/wearable/ui-components/scroll-bars#fast_scroll_index) to solve this problem. But according to the linked documentation it's not available in a Tizen native API app.

What is the best way to implement quick navigation in a huge circle genlist in a Tizen native API app? Do I have to come up with something myself like an upstream A-Z list to link into the circle genlist or is there some recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fast rotary action is not supported in native application for now.

if you want to implement fast navigation with rotary events,
you can manually call

```
elm_genlist_item_bring_in(Elm_Object_Item *item, Elm_Genlist_Scrollto_Type *type)
```

to bring item in the viewport, with handling the provided rotary event.

see more about rotary events,
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/rotary-events/

Thank you.